# It's impossible to do mouse over second time (rect is undefined)

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to move mouse to element which was hidden on another element (before first hover over). After second hover over I see error:

> TypeError: rect is undefined

I tried to add any kind of expectations, timeouts, scripts for scrollintoview. 
I should add that for chrome all works fine.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

...

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(cardElement).perform();
WebElement formatElement = cardElement.findElement(By.xpath("..."));
Thread.sleep(10000); // different kinds of expectations 
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(formatElement).perform();
```

Expected: Card element changes view.

Actual :

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: TypeError: rect is undefined

Comment: Welcome to SO.Can you please share url if possible (or any sample url matches your scenario)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925310/how-to-hover-over-and-click-on-an-invisible-element-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Hover over and click on an invisible element using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925310/how-to-hover-over-and-click-on-an-invisible-element-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Does the first hover work? Do you see the expected hover behavior? Is the second element visible after the first hover? These are things you should make more clear in your question.